# Cannot execute PUT method on browser

Tags: angular, cors

I'm traing to create an angular app

Well, when I call the API from Postman it work
but when I try to call it using HTTP.put on a browser (firefox or chrome )
I always have this error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:5001/api/users/set-main-photo/25. (Reason: Did not find method in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’).

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:5001/api/users/set-main-photo/25. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I make some research and I addid this to my header using the Interceptor
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:   GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    *

still same issue

any help please?

Note : HTTP.GET and HTTP.POST works fine
Thank you

Comment: Have you read and understood the following? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

Answer (score -1):

You've run into a common issue when starting out with development.
Due to security issues you are restricted from calls across domain names without it being explicitly configured to do so.
Depending on your API you can allow any origin to call it.

Setting the headers on your request itself will not allow you to bypass this restriction you need to configure the API.

You can read
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to get a better understanding.

Or as stated above this previous post covers the topic as well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/9994146

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this using

```
  app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
```

before it was

```
 app.UseCors( x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
```

Thank you

Comment: You're allowing arbitrary origins with credentials. This is very insecure! You're basically throwing the Same-Origin Policy out the window. You should reconsider.

Comment: Yes but now i'm in localhost so no problem then I think, i'm still in dev
any way thank you